# How to write build target for sources from different paths?

Tags: makefile

*At first, I'm a noobie in makefiles...*
I have next targets in my **Makefile**:

```
$(BUILD_PATH)/%.o: %.c $(GEN_PATH)/%.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(HEADERS) -c $< -o $@

server: $(BUILD_PATH)/main.o $(BUILD_PATH)/socket.o $(BUILD_PATH)/settings.o $(BUILD_PATH)/options.o
    $(CC) -L$(LIB_PATH) -Wl,-rpath=$(LIB_PATH) $(FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $(DIST_PATH)/server $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

I specified that object files must be compiled from the current folder and `$(GEN_PATH)` but it doesn't work and I am getting error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '../build/server/options.o', needed by 'server'.  Stop.
```

**How can I write this rule right?**

**P.S.** It's not primary question but how can I write my input targets shorter? I tried this variant:

```
server: $(BUILD_PATH)/%.o
    $(CC) -L$(LIB_PATH) -Wl,-rpath=$(LIB_PATH) $(FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $(DIST_PATH)/server $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: There is something a bit strange with your first rule. Why do you declare `$(GEN_PATH)/%.c` as a prerequisite? Is it a header file, instead of a C source file? If yes, wouldn't it be better to name it `$(GEN_PATH)/%.h`?

Comment: Apparently `BUILD_PATH` expands as `../build/server` and make tells you that it does not know how to build `../build/server/options.o`. The reason is probably that it did not find `options.c` or `$(GEN_PATH)/options.c`. Did you check that these files exist?

Comment: You can optimize your `server` rule with: `server: $(patsubst %.c,$(BUILD_PATH)/%.o,$(wildcard *.c))`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet thank you,  it helped.  And I got that I can't do as I wrote the first target.  I have subdivided it in two targets.  Now it works.

Comment: Were you trying to compile two source files into one object file? You were using the [automatic variable `$<`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables), which expands to the *first* prerequisite.